# Which file format takes less space in sink() function?

Tags: r

I am running a long time script (gets information from the server), which runs the whole day and `sink()` function saves the output to `.txt` format. I heard that sometimes `sink()` function stops abruptly if a huge file is created. In my case, the file size is approx. 100-200mb. Which file format is better to use in order to save some space? or is there are any other functions to save data to my computer?

Comment: Your options will depend a lot on what sort of output you are saving and how it's implemented in your workflow. Are you saving data frames? Other R objects? Console outputs from `message`/`cat`/`print`? Do you need `sink`'s capability to append to a single file, building it up potentially one line at a time, or are you writing in larger batches? Do you need the files to be human readable? Readable by programs other than R?

Comment: Console output is message. and I append the data to the today file using ```sink(file=paste(path,paste("Version1", Sys.Date(), sep = "_"),".txt",sep = "", append = TRUE))```

Comment: In that case, I think you have limited options other than `sink` - not many functions capture message output. You might check out the [`logger` package](https://github.com/daroczig/logger) (or some of the other logging packages mentioned in its README). Alternately, you could create hourly files instead of daily files to keep them smaller.

Comment: but if I use `sink` , which file format is better to use (based on memory)?

Comment: `sink` writes text, so you don't have other options for the file format.

Comment: You could compress the files after you are done writing to them - and for (probably repetitive) text files this would drastically reduce the size on disk. But you won't be able to write to a compressed file, this would only reduce the size after you are done writing to the file.

Answer (score 0):

The first option that comes to mind is the `feather` package. It stores data frames in binary format, which allows you to push and pull data frames easily. The data should also be lightweight in memory compared to traditional options like `sink()`.

An example workflow would be:

```
#write data
library(feather)
path <- "my_data.feather"
write_feather(df, path)

#read data
df <- read_feather(path)
```

Without having your data on hand to benchmark myself, try it out, and let me know if it's indeed faster

Comment: It is working with data frames, however, I get messages in the console from the server, which this package cannot capture

Comment: Oh it wasn't clear that you also wanted to capture console message. I think @Gregor Thomas may be right that there's no obvious alternative to what you want to achieve